# ssh key auth still asks for password (no passphrase set)

Tags: ssh, passwords

Trying to set up SSH to my CentOS VPS with key auth and no pass phrase so that I can auto-connect from my Debian 7 local server. I've gone as far as copying and pasting from two different guides on the net ([here](http://www.debuntu.org/secure-your-ssh-server-with-publicprivate-key-authentification/) and [here](http://www.rebol.com/docs/ssh-auto-login.html)) and I still get asked for a password. (not pass phrase)

My remote sshd_config Authentication section, cut off just before the kerberos section:

```
    # Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandRunAs nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# RhostsRSAAuthentication and HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication yes

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

Remote /var/log/secure has no errors:

```
Jun 13 07:02:14 *remote host* sshd[4206]: Accepted password for admin from *my-ip* port 48919 ssh2
Jun 13 07:02:15 *remote host* sshd[4206]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user admin by (uid=0)
Jun 13 07:02:20 *remote host* sshd[4220]: Received disconnect from *my-ip*: 11: disconnected by user
Jun 13 07:02:20 *remote host* sshd[4206]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user admin
```

and verbose connecting on client has no errors, just sends private key and skips to password:

```
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: *local/user/home*/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: *local/user/home*/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: *local/user/home*/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: *local/user/home*/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: *local/user/home*/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: *local/user/home*/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
admin@*remote server*'s password:
```

After reading suggestions and following the second guide, I've tried setting both 755 and 600 on everything in local and remote ~/.ssh/ directories, and it still doesn't work. As I said, I copied and pasted this command:

```
cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys
```

to copy the key into the authorized_keys file; I copied and pasted all commands from both guides to ensure nothing is wrong in my configuration.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you copy `id_rsa.pub` and put it on the *server's* `authorized_keys`?

Comment: yes. I've gone through the process 3 times now, deleting everything in local and remote ~/.ssh/ directories each time. The authorized_keys file exists only on the remote server; just did a ls to make sure: 
`[admin@*remote host* ~]$ ls ~/.ssh/
authorized_keys  id_rsa`

Comment: Is there a way to check the id_rsa against authorized_keys in a way that will plainly tell me if they match or not? I'm guessing the pub and private keys are different somehow, so I can't just compare, right?

Comment: The only key in `authorized_keys` should be `id_rsa.pub`, so `[local]$ md5sum id_rsa.pub` and `[remote]$ md5sum authorized_keys` should give the same checksum.

Comment: Can you try changing `AuthorizedKeysFile ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to `AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys`?

Comment: Also, why is there an `id_rsa` on the remote machine?

Comment: md5 sums all match. Changed the config file as you suggested. Removed remote id_rsa. Still asking for pass, client is still offering local id_rsa with no reaction from the server, same as in OP.

Comment: Sorry, I am at a loss. Maybe somebody else can help you.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I guess I'll open a ticket with the VPS provider, but they won't be responding any time soon if anyone else wants to help. lol

Comment: Comment out that `AuthorizedKeysFile` line.

Comment: Just a few more things you may like to try: double check group and other don't have rwx permission on `.ssh` and `.ssh/*`, ssh from the remote to itself (localhost) using a public key, restart sshd and/or reboot, run sshd in a terminal with verbose debugging using `sshd -ddd` (kill it first or run it on a different port). Good luck.

Comment: `PasswordAuthentication yes` should be actually set to `no` if you don't want to be asked for a Password. And, perhaps you should have also a look at `UsePAM` (and set it too to `no`).

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong value for AuthorizedKeysFile parameter. From man sshd_config:

AuthorizedKeysFile may contain tokens of the form %T which are substituted during connection set-up.
The following tokens are defined: %% is replaced by a literal '%', %h is replaced by the home directory of the user being authenticated and %u is replaced by the username of that user.
After expansion, AuthorizedKeysFile is taken to be an absolute path or one relative to the user's home directory.    The default is ".ssh/authorized_keys".

Comment: It doesn't look to be changed from the default to me. The setting there matched the last two sentences of your post.

Comment: Your sshd_config contains line: AuthorizedKeysFile ~/.ssh/authorized_keys  which is wrong. It should ne %h/.ssh/authorized_keys or just commented out

Comment: "AuthorizedKeysFile is taken to be an absolute path **or one relative to the user's home directory**. The default is **".ssh/authorized_keys"**. <- are you saying that the default is the absolute path of `/.ssh/authorized_keys`? No, because it's interpreted as **relative to the user's home directory** as the documentation you just quoted states.

Comment: Default doesn't contain leading slash, so yes, it is related to user's home directory. BUT leading tilde will be interpreted to something else, most likely - to home of sshd user.

Comment: Then I understand, so maybe that was changed manually which broke it :)

Comment: This was actually discussed in the comments above. It was set up with ~/.ssh/ out-of-the-box. I changed it to %h last night and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the help. I guess you all will hate to hear that it just magically fixed itself today. That's right: I woke up, installed some other software on the VPS, (some irssi-related things) rebooted, (even though I tried that last night, along with reloading the sshd service) went to log in to SSH to try some suggestions, and it gave me a new `WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!` message. Since I've been doing `chmod -R 755 .ssh/` lately on my local SSH files because 600 won't let it issue the key for some weird reason, I used `chmod -R 700 .ssh/` after this warning and now everything works fine. I really don't know what happened. Again, thanks everyone for your time.

Comment: chmod 600 (rw-------) on the .ssh/ directory is wrong.  Directories need to have the x bit set, so 700 (rwx------).  Files within the directory would be fine at 600.

Comment: Now in CentOS7, if the .ssh folder is not set to 700, it rejects the public key authentication at all

Answer (score 1):

Another solution for SELinux preventing sshd from reading $HOME/.ssh is to use restorecon, see my answser here https://superuser.com/a/764020/213743.

Answer (score 0):

If SELinux on the system, edit `/etc/selinux/config` and change

```
SELINUX=enforcing
```

to

```
SELINUX=permissive
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that can cause `we did not send a packet, disable method` is if the server is configured to reject your login. For example, if you try to log in as `root` when the configuration contains `PermitRootLogin no`.